# Border-styles on CSS table-like matrix, without extra classes

Tags: html, border, tabular, css

I'm making a table-like layout using only CSS. With all the cells set to `float:left` the container `.matrix` is wide enough for 4 cells horizontally.

```
<div class="matrix">
    <!-- first row -->
    <div class="cell">Cell contents</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell contents</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell contents</div>
    <div class="cell right">Cell contents</div>
    <!-- last row -->
    <div class="cell last">Cell contents</div>
    <div class="cell last">Cell contents</div>
    <div class="cell last">Cell contents</div>
    <div class="cell last right">Cell contents</div>
</div>
```

To control where the border-styles are applied I use `.last` and `.right` classes to omit border-styles on the edges:

```
.cell {
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    border-right:1px solid red;
}
.right {
    border-right:none;
}
.last {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone has a technique where I achieve the same result/logic - but without the need for the extra classes.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: If this is "table-like", is there a reason not to use tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution without using extra classes, CSS3 selectors or wrapper elements. By giving the container an `overflow:hidden`, and shifting the cells slightly like so:

```
.matrix{
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.cell {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    position:relative;
    bottom:-1px;
    padding:5px;
    left:-1px;
}
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KBMvL/5/

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, however it uses some selectors which older browsers can not understand. Your solution is the safest one, therefore it is the one most common.

There is a plenty of new selectors in CSS3, some of them can solve your problem. Here is an interesting list of [useful selectors](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it using CSS `:nth-child` selectors

```
.matrix{
    width:400px;
}

.cell {
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    border-right:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    padding:.5em;
}

.cell:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+8){
    border-bottom:none;
}

.cell:nth-child(4), .cell:nth-child(8){
    border-right:none;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KBMvL/

Comment: This relies on CSS3, correct? And is incompatible with < IE9 etc?

Comment: That's right @Orolin.  Everyone but IE8 and below supports.  If you need to support <IE9, then you could use this and use some jQuery to apply the styles for the non-compliant browsers.

Comment: @Orolin - if you reverse the borders, you can use `:first-child` instead, which *is* supported by IE7 and IE8.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a wrapper element around the rows, then you can use CSS `:last-child` to deal with both the cells on the right and the ones on the bottom.

I'll assume your wrapper element is also going to be a `<div>`:

```
.cell {
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    border-right:1px solid red;
}

.matrix>div:last-child>.cell, .matrix>div>.cell:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

But note that `:last-child` is not supported by IE8 and earlier.

You might have more luck setting the opposite borders (ie top and left), and using `:first-child` instead to blank out the leftmost and topmost cells, because `:first-child` is supported by IE7 and IE8. The end result would be exactly the same.

You can find out more about browser support for CSS selectors here: http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

If you need to use `:last-child`, and you need to support IE7/8, then you might be able to get it working by using a javascript library such as [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/).

However after all that, I would also say that given the wrapper element I've added for the rows, we end up with the same basic structure as an HTML table. So the question is why not simply use a table? Then you can use `border-collapse` to achieve similar results.

Regarding this last point, I know you put 'tableless' as a tag on the question, so I assume you're working to a table-less design. However, if the data is indeed tabular in nature, then there's nothing wrong with using a table. Table-less design is intended to stop people using tables for arbitrary page layout, but tables are still perfectly valid when used in the right context. The description in the question does make it sound very much as if your example falls into this category.

Hope that helps.